# Capture screen remotely of iphone device.

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programatically capture video of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278248/programatically-capture-video-of-screen)

I am building an app in which i have to capture the screen of iPhone mobile (rooted phone) remotely... 
Means i have to capture screen from one iPhone to another iPhone remotely...

please suggest me...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically capture screen snapshots, you can:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)saveScreenSnapshot:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // do what you want with this image; I frequently just drop it in the device's photo album
    //
    // UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Alternatively, can get a PNG representation of that `image` via:

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

You obviously have to add the `QuartzCore.framework` to your target app's libraries.

Comment: is that possible to captur screen of ios device? when application goes to background that time whatever the window is open can i take scree capture?